# How to fix Ubuntu GUI after installing windows 11 dual boot

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I recently installed windows 11 on my second hdd and since then I face issues with ubuntu improperly loading GUI.

Ubuntu loads to tty1 instead of the graphical user interface (GUI).

I have managed to fix this temporarily.

To address this issue, I have been able to enter a full shell by executing the command `sudo mount / -o remount,rw`. However, after each reboot, the domain resolution breaks and I have been temporarily fixing it by adding the `nameserver 8.8.8.8` using the command `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`.

solves until next reboot and then I face the same bugs

Here is additional information:

fedorovn19@fedorovn19-Nitro-AN515-45:~$ sudo fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.

1. Remove dirty bit
2. No action
   [12?q]? 1

*** Filesystem was changed ***
The changes have not yet been written, you can still choose to leave the
filesystem unmodified:

1. Write changes
2. Leave filesystem unchanged
   [12?q]? 1
   /dev/nvme0n1p1: 201 files, 9450/130812 clusters

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` did not help

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` did not help

`mount -t ext4` changes from ro to rw

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is probably unrelated to the Windows installation, unless you changed the drive partitioning during installation. Your logs indicate your root filesystem has become corrupt, which can happen if the computer loses power suddenly or if the partition size is changed.

It will probably be easier to re-install Ubuntu than solve the filesystem corruption if the standard fsck tool is unable to do so automatically. Before running fsck, making an image of the disk is advisable as fsck may make some of your data permanently unrecoverable in the process of trying to fix the filesystem.